# Using Yii1 and Yii2 in the same project

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I had a project in Yii1.x and now I am using Yii2 for the same projects

Project hierarchy is something like this

```
Project1(yii1)/all yii files +  project2(yii2)

project2(yii2)/frontend + /common + /backend
```

Now I want to know if is it possible to use `project2/common/models` in `project1/protected/controllers`

How can I achieve this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing it, instead it's better to completely rewrite old application in Yii2.

But in case of partial migrating, please read [this paragraph](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1) in Special Topics Section in Official Guide.

Here are some important code snippets from there:

**1)** Modification of entry script:

```
// include the customized Yii class described below
require(__DIR__ . '/../components/Yii.php');

// configuration for Yii 2 application
$yii2Config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/yii2/web.php');
new yii\web\Application($yii2Config); // Do NOT call run()

// configuration for Yii 1 application
$yii1Config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/yii1/main.php');
Yii::createWebApplication($yii1Config)->run();
```

**2)** Combination of `Yii` classes:

```
$yii2path = '/path/to/yii2';
require($yii2path . '/BaseYii.php'); // Yii 2.x

$yii1path = '/path/to/yii1';
require($yii1path . '/YiiBase.php'); // Yii 1.x

class Yii extends \yii\BaseYii
{
    // copy-paste the code from YiiBase (1.x) here
}

Yii::$classMap = include($yii2path . '/classes.php');
// register Yii 2 autoloader via Yii 1
Yii::registerAutoloader(['Yii', 'autoload']);
// create the dependency injection container
Yii::$container = new yii\di\Container;
```

Usage of `Yii` class:

```
echo get_class(Yii::app()); // outputs 'CWebApplication'
echo get_class(Yii::$app);  // outputs 'yii\web\Application'
```

Comment: i am a beginner in this framework so i have no idea what that documentation is trying to say.. Is there any other step by step tutorial available which i can follow??

Comment: @arogachev, the docs says >For example, you can create Active Record classes and use them to work with databases.
But how do I achieve this in a yii1 app ?