# Combining Yii-2 and Yii-1 apps

Tags: php, yii, migration, yii2, yii1.x

I am using Yii2 advanced template and trying to move my existing Yii-1 app inside a Yii-2 app. My goal is that Yii-1 runs as it is, without any changes. Then I can move individual functionality from my Yii-1 app into Yii-2. Thus I can selectively migrate from Yii-1 to Yii-2

- Is this a viable approach?
- Is there any other way to move from Yii-1 to Yii-2, in parts?

For reference, [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1) describes the opposite of what I want to do i.e. put Yii-2 in Yii-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Yii1 and Yii2 in the same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816134/using-yii1-and-yii2-in-the-same-project)

Comment: Please find below links for step by step upgrade guide :

   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-intro-upgrade-from-v1.html

  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-yii-2-with-yii-1

Comment: Even though the doc describes a way that would be not very good for you it is the best way to do it currently

Answer (score 0):

Have thought about this as well. Think there are issues with combining the two though. For example user authentication. Will the models and controllers pickup the authentication from one framework and be able to use it in the other. Have not really seen any documentation on these types of questions.